# Using simple RNN to identify a simple dynamic linear system

Tags: control-engineering, linear-systems, system-identification

I have been trying to identify a simple linear second order system (e.g. a pendulum or a mass-spring system), by simulating it in Python using backwards-euler method and then feeding the step changes in force as Input (x) to simple RNN network, and recorded Position (y) as an output. It is assumed that Driving Force from the timestep t-2 correlates with Displacement in timestep t.

Since model has two states I have used RNN with only two hidden units (states)as this structure is equivalent to state-space description of linear system and should be sufficient to represent the behavior of the system (as discussed [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8579) and described in more details here [here](https://aleksandarhaber.com/using-recurrent-neural-networks-and-keras-tensorflow-to-learn-input-output-behaviour-of-dynamical-systems/)). Further more, since the relationship between inputs-states-outputs is linear, only linear activation functions are used.

Interestingly enough, solver is for some reason not able to fit the NN to match the output from the training/validation set, and as you can see below, seem to only "feed-thru" only the step like input changes, whereas the oscillatory effect that is supposed to come from the interaction between the states (velocity, position), is not captured.

(Note: Larger networks of 32 units as well as LSTM have been used, but still with poor results, indicating problem is elsewhere. Training and validation error are both barely reducing within first 250 epochs)

Network is described by the code below:

> model=Sequential()
>
> model.add(SimpleRNN(units=2, activation='linear', input_shape=(len(Input), 1),use_bias = False))
> model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear', use_bias = False))
>
> model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
>
> model.summary()

And fit using:

> model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

Training data and the results are shown on the following images:

[image]

**Image: Training Input-Output data recorded from the state-space model**

[image]

**Image: Totally incorrect prediction output**

I have managed to fit the model perfectly using Feedforward neural network with same ammount of units, giving as input vector of current input and previous two states as follows: [Input(t) Output(t-1) Output(t-2)]. (something like ARX model)

It seems I am missing something about the structure of RNN and the data format they expect.

Also model.get_weights() produces following output, not sure how to interpret it exactly:

[array([[-0.29872632, -0.17957304]], dtype=float32),
array([[ 0.8877555 , -0.46031553],
[ 0.46031553,  0.8877554 ]], dtype=float32),
array([[-0.73704493],
[ 0.8689412 ]], dtype=float32)]

Comment: (1) You have given us a _story_, but you have not asked a _question_.  Please _edit your question_ to _actually ask a question_.  (2) Instead of wedging a neural network description into the shape of a system identification problem, why not use the very rich and varied literature for system identification as your starting point?  (3) "It is assumed that Driving Force from the timestep t-2 correlates with Displacement in timestep t." -- that's probably not even close to true.  If you're baking that assumption into your RNN, that may be a big part of the problem.

Comment: (1) You are right, I skipped the question, I will edit the comment, tho the question is rather self-explanatory - why does RNN fail to correctly identify the system dynamics? (2) Do you have something particular on your mind? I am familiar with some concepts from sys. ident. theory, but am right now exploring the possibilites of using RNNs to do system identification of linear and non-linear dynamics and found A.Havers interesting, tho it leaves some questions open to me. (I find it interesting that he starts from the point of equivalence of RNN and state-space model)

Comment: (3) Could you please provide argumentation to why are you certain that is not true?
In case of second order continous LTI system, input would be directly proportional to acceleration which then integrates into X2 which is velocity, which in turn integrates into Position. As far as I remember from my control system studies, from discretisation directly follows that in such a system discretized ouput (in terms of position measured in time t) depends on Input and states from previous 2 steps. I would appreciate if you could be more concrete in what you think is wrong about it.